# Is there a specific size limit for WebDriver IWebElements?

Tags: c#, xml, selenium, firefox, webdriver

I have a C# application that opens a website and reads a raw XML dump that gets generated inside of a "textarea" CSS element. I am using the Selenium Firefox web driver.

```
 IWebElement body = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("textarea"));     
 string xmlData = body.Text;
```

No errors are thrown and the string *xmlData* contains part of the data but not all of it - 902 lines of text compared to 32,255 lines if I copy and paste it directly from the website. What surprises me is that *xmlData* seems to be missing a large chunk of data out of the middle, not the beginning or end.

Is there a limit to the size of IWebElement and what are my alternatives to capturing this XML dump?

EDIT: A bit more info.

Here is the output of *xmlData* where the block of data is missing. Notice the ellipses.

```
 <row>
   <value>ATL</value>
   <value>Overnight</value>
   ...s:nil="true" />
   <value xs:nil="true" />
   <value xs:nil="true" />
 </row>
```

And here is the data copied directly from the XML dump on the website showing the full data:

```
<row>
  <value>ATL</value>
  <value>Overnight</value>
  <value>737</value>
  <value>3BX</value>
  <value>SIC</value>
</row>

*Insert thousands of rows here*

<row>
  <value>TPA</value>
  <value>Turnaround</value>
  <value xs:nil="true" />
  <value xs:nil="true" />
  <value xs:nil="true" />
</row>
```

Comment: Does it always break the string on 903rd line? If so, have you checked that it doesn't have any special characters on 902nd line that could break a string in certain cases?

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the `HTMLTextAreaElement.value` property instead:

```
 IWebElement body = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("textarea"));     
 string xmlData = body.GetAttribute("value");
```

Answer (score 0):

The limitation turned out to be Visual Studio's visualizing tool (text visualizer) and not a limitation with IWEbElements.